# MVCSitemapProvider current node not detected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSiteMapProvider 3.3.3.0 and have a file `MvcSiteMap.sitemap` which contains two nodes defined as follows:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Node1" controller="MyController" action="MyAction" type="A" />
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Node2" controller="MyController" action="MyAction" type="B" />
```

My routes in global.asax.cs are configured "out of the box", so the URLs are:

```
Node 1: http://server/MyController/MyAction?type=A
Node 2: http://server/MyController/MyAction?type=B
```

Now if I navigate to Node 2, I find that `MenuHelper.GetCurrentNode()` returns Node 1.

Why is this and is there a way to get MvcSiteMapProvider to recognize a current node based on the querystring parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is possible although I have not tested this. You should check out the wiki at their github repository. It has some usefull information but it still lacks some basic examples.

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.
 I got around this problem using a custom DynamicNodeProvider, but it doesn't seem to fit in your case.